# Books on Brahma Sutras

Tags: vedanta, adi-shankaracharya, brahma-sutras

What are the best books to get started to learn Brahma Sutras. English translation of Sankara's commentary is what I am looking for.

Has anyone read V Panoli's translation and please suggest your thoughts. I know this is hard vedanta, but I want to make a genuine effort to understand

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras  This is translation by Swami Vireswarananda.

Comment: English translation of Shankara's commentary by Swami Gambhirananda is very good. George Thibaut's translation is also good and available online - https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe34/

Answer (score 1):

Brahma-Sutra by Swami Vireswarananda published by Advaita Ashrama is a beautiful book. In contains relevant parts of the other important commentaries also. Swami Vireswarananda was the tenth President of the Ramakrishna Math and Mission and a disciple of Maa Sarada Devi.